# Double is not rounded using Math.Round function?

Tags: .net, math, rounding

I'm creating new model and one of the model's properties is BruttoPrice (nullable-double type) and to that property i want to assign my Item3 (nullable-double type) value but rounded to 2 decimal places - so i"m using Math.Round function but it's not working

**Assigning item3 to bruttoPrice**

[image: .]

```
var model = new Model
            {
                BruttoPrice = Math.Round(val.Item3 ?? 0, 2),
            };
```

**My model output**

[image: .]

Comment: The Null-coalescing operator cannot be applied on data of `double` type. That should throw an error. How is your code even working?

Comment: My bad, item 3 is a nullable double that's why i need to do 'item3 ?? 0' in case of null value

Comment: Please post code in the question itself, not screenshots of code.

Comment: Use `decimal` for currency-related quantities to avoid the pitfalls of floating point representation.

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you're expecting a `double` to be able to store an *exact* value to a given number of *decimal* digits.

The precise `double` value closest to 153.4 is 153.400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625 - which is being displayed as 153.40000000000001.

There's nothing more that `Math.Round` can do there - there's no `double` value closer to 153.4.

If this is just for formatting purposes, you should *format* to 2 decimal places rather than rounding the data.

If the actual value matters, and you want precise decimal values, you should use `decimal` instead of `double`.